# add all values with matching key in multidimensional json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am working on a php script where I have a json api array that looks something like this --

```
[body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [api] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [status] => 200
                    [message] => GET stat....
                    [results] => 379
                    [filters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => gameId
                            [1] => playerId
                        )

                    [statistics] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [gameId] => 17
                                    [totReb] => 7
                                    [assists] => 5
                                    [pFouls] => 4
                                    [steals] => 3
                                    [turnovers] => 2
                                    [blocks] => 0
                                    [plusMinus] => 9
                                    [playerId] => 265
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [gameId] => 24
                                    [teamId] => 7
                                    [totReb] => 
                                    [assists] => 
                                    [pFouls] => 
                                    [steals] => 
                                    [turnovers] => 
                                    [blocks] => 
                                    [plusMinus] => 
                                    [playerId] => 265
                                )
```

And I am trying to get the values for each object to then output the total, so for each **[?] => stdClass Object** it will get the specified key and total the value.

How can I add all the values from one key?

Comment: What is your key? which values you want to add / count as total? can you try explain better what error do you get or what non desire output you get?

Comment: i will be using multiple keys in my script, so for example this key - `[steals] => 3`

Comment: did my post helped you?

Answer (score 1):

First get the array of statistics (the one you want to loop and sum on). Then use `array_column` to extract only  specific key and then `array_sum` for summing it.

This is pseudo but should give you the idea:

```
$arr = $obj->body->api->statistics;
$keyToSum = "steals";
$totalSteals = array_sum(array_column($arr, $keyToSum));
```

Reference: [array-column](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [array-sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is one custom function I have which fetches column data recursively like [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
function array_column_recursive(array $haystack, $needle) {
    $found = [];
    array_walk_recursive($haystack, function($value, $key) use (&$found, $needle) {
        if ($key == $needle)
            $found[] = $value;
    });
    return $found;
}
echo array_sum(array_column_recursive($arr, 'steals'));
```

Source [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#119954).